# SpriteKit: Creating a tile based maze

Tags: swift, algorithm, sprite-kit, maze

I want to create a game with a maze(not really) in it. The whole map should be surrounded by wall and inside these walls there should be a maze. This maze should be randomly created. On every tile where no wall is placed, the player should be randomly placed. Is there a build in class/function in SpriteKit that can fulfill my requirements or do I need to come up with an algorithm by myself?

PS: A possible visualization would be the game PacMan with randomly created stages.

Comment: what you want to do is called a procedurally generated algorithm,  this is not something built into XCode in any way, since there are many different ways to achieve results of a maze.  raywenderlich.com is a great site for resources on the matter,  here is one example:http://www.raywenderlich.com/66062/procedural-level-generation-games-using-cellular-automaton-part-1

Comment: Do you also have a source using Swift not Objective-C?

Comment: I am sure there are some out there,  was just letting you know what the algorithm is actually called

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tile map to create your maze/levels, but you will need to write the code to do this. It will be a tough algorithm to ensure that each level is playable/winnable. Might be worth starting with defined layouts to get the game play right, then add in random generation.

Comment: What do you espacially mean with an tile map? Are there maybe some libraries?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x. You can use spritekite with a 3rd party tile map library